# Получить id элемента с определенным классом по которому кликнули?

Tags: javascript

**Вопрос 1:** Нагуглил 2 варианта получения данных элементов по которым кликнули, какой из них лучше использовать?

```
// этот?
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
// или этот?
document.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
};
// Ваш вариант?
```

Пробую получать данные элемента, по которому кликнули:

```
// получаю id элемента (если он конечно имеется)
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
});

// пробую получить id того элемента, у которого имеется класс 'test'

// синтаксическая ошибка...
document.getElementsByClassName('test').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
// работает только с первым элементом...
document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

**Вопрос 2:** Как правильно получать id элемента лишь с определенным классом, по которому кликнули?

Comment: 1. Лучше использовать первый вариант. 2. Использовать цикл.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko 1. понял. 2. - можно пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('test')) { return }
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Используй jq

```js
$('.nameClass').on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="youId" class="nameClass">Text</div>
```